# HOw to use -m (match) in iptables

Tags: iptables

i want to know what is the difference between these two commands

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

-

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, since the `tcp` match is implicit when filtering the `tcp` protocol.

Comment: SO IT MEANS -m option is only important for STATE matches , otherwise no need to use for tcp , udp , icmp

Comment: If either no options imply a match or if an option implies multiple matches then you need to specify a match. Otherwise, `iptables` will figure out what you mean in the command line.